# How to get $(1-x^2)^{1/2}\theta(1-x)$ continuous?

Tags: function-construction, discontinuity

The function $f(x)=(1-x^2)^{1/2}\theta(1-x),$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function, should be a continuous function for $x\geq-1$. Another way to define the same function is,

$$
g(x)= \begin{cases}(1-x^2)^{1/2}, & \lambda\leq 1,\\ 0, & \lambda > 1.\end{cases}
$$

I would like to use `FunctionContinuous` to test the claim. But I get `False` for

```
FunctionContinuous[{g[x], x >= -1}, x]
```

and `True` for

```
FunctionContinuous[{f[x], x >= -1}, x]
```

with

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{(1 - x^2)^(1/2), x <= 1}, {0, x > 1}}]

g[x_] := (1 - x^2)^(1/2) HeavisideTheta[1 - x]
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Please include your function definitions in Mathematica code, and not just in Latex.

Comment: Annoyingly, `FunctionContinuous[{Sqrt[1 - x^2] UnitStep[1 - x], x > -1}, x]` gives `False`, but `FunctionContinuous[{Sqrt[1 - x^2] UnitStep[1 - x] // PiecewiseExpand, x > -1}, x]` gives `True`. Please [report this to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Comment: Are you aware that the docs for `HeavisideTheta[]` explicitly say that `HeavisideTheta[0]` doesn't evaluate?

Comment: @J.M. thank you for your comments. Yes, I checked that `HeavisideTheta[0]` does not evaluate, but the function `g[1]` does evaluate `0` as expected. Does it matter?

Comment: It's one reason I can think of as to why your function is not playing nice with `FunctionContinuous[]`; I would use `HeavisideTheta[]` only in places where I would be evaluating integral (transforms)...

Comment: @J.M. thanks! Also annoyingly, `FunctionContinuous[{(1 - x^2)^(1) HeavisideTheta[1 - x], x >= -1}, x]` (with expoent 1 not 1/2) gives `True` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can be real-continuous only within its real domain. Mathematica's FunctionDomain gives the intersection of real domains of all subexpressions. Hence a point is in the real domain only if all subexpressions, not just the whole function, are defined and real-valued. g[x] contains (1 - x^2)^(1/2) that is not real-valued for x>1, and HeavisideTheta[1 - x] that is undefined for x==1. f[x] is explicitly 0 for x>1.

```
In[3]:= FunctionDomain[f[x], x]                                                 

Out[3]= x >= -1

In[4]:= FunctionDomain[g[x], x]                                                 

Out[4]= -1 <= x < 1
```